# How do I delete discord bot message after time?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

For some reason the `message.delete({timeout: 5000});` statement does not work inside the if statement. It does work earlier in the code. Any ideas why?

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const config = require('./config.json');

client.on("ready", async () => {
    
    console.log('--> Online');
    
    status = client.users.cache.get(config.user).presence.status;
    channel = client.channels.cache.get(config.channel);
    
    embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        embed.setDescription('I am ONLINE');
        embed.setColor('#00ccff');
    message = await channel.send(embed);
    
    message.delete({timeout: 5000});
```

It seems to work here ^^

```js
    setInterval(() => {

        user = client.users.cache.get(config.user);
        updated = client.users.cache.get(config.user).presence.status;

        if(updated != status) {
            status = updated;

            if(updated == 'online') {
                channel.send(embed);
                message.delete({timeout: 5000});
            } 
        
        
        } else {
            return
        }
    }, 1250);
});

client.login(config.token);
```

Not here ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that second piece of code to work in the same way that your first, working example works, this is how you would need to change the `setInterval` and its contents:

```
setInterval(async () => {

    user = client.users.cache.get(config.user);
    updated = client.users.cache.get(config.user).presence.status;

    if(updated != status) {
        status = updated;

        if(updated == 'online') {
            var message = await channel.send(embed);
            message.delete({timeout: 5000});
        } 
    
    
    } else {
        return
    }
}, 1250);
```

The two major errors you made here are:

1. You did not define the `message` variable. You simply did
   `channel.send(embed)` without putting its result in that variable,
   like so: `var message = await channel.send(embed)`;
2. Sending a message in a channel is asynchronous. In other words,
   because sending a message requires your code to make a request to
   the Discord API and for the Discord API to then interpret and
   respond to your request, it takes some time for the message to
   actually be sent. As such, your `message.delete()` line is called
   before the Discord API even gets a chance to send the message in the
   first place, so the code thinks it is going to be deleting a
   non-existent message. This is why you need to use `async`/`await`
   here (which you did in your first piece of code but not your
   second); `await` will wait until the request is completed (aka until
   the Promise is resolved) before continuing to the rest of your code.
   Therefore, by using `await`, the message deletion timer will only
   begin after the message has successfully been sent, creating the
   functionality you want.

You can alternatively use `.then()`, but async/await is designed to be a neater and easier way of handling asynchronous Promises like these. Note that in order for `await` to work, you must set the function it is running in as `async`. In this scenario, you need to add `async` before the method running in the `setInterval`, as shown in my above solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do like this:

```
channel.send(embed).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 5000 }))
            })
```

Edit:

Your command doesn't work because in the first code you did

```
    message = await channel.send(embed);
    
    message.delete({timeout: 5000});
```

And in the second code you did:

```
      channel.send(embed);
                message.delete({timeout: 5000});
```

You forgot to add

```
 message = await channel.send(embed);
```

But my code works too

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy to do that you just go to the message the bot should send and then put this

```
.then(m => m.delete({timeout: <the time you want it to be deleted in milliseconds>}))
```

This should 100% work if you have discord 12v.

Example:

```
message.channel.send("This message will be deleted in 5 seconds!")
.then(m => m.delete({timeout: 5000}))
```

Or

```
message.reply("This message will be deleted in 5 seconds!")
.then(m => m.delete({timeout: 5000}))
```

You can all ways use any name for the `m => m.delete` like `msg => msg.delete` , but it should not be as the same as the `message.send` name.

I mean not like  `message.channel.send("This message will be deleted in 5 seconds!") .then(message => message.delete({timeout: 5000}))`

You can even use this method for every timeout you want like `m.reply` or `m.edit` !