# How do I make my custom discord bot to delete an embed it sent out in a few seconds after the msg has been sent

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, coding-style

I want my bot to delete an embed it sends out when someone uses a cuss word. I want it to delete that embed in 5-6 seconds take 5 or 6 so it takes up less space in the area.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Client();
const token = 'tokenhere';

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    bot.user.setActivity('YOU', { type: 'WATCHING' });
    console.log('This bot is online!');
});

bot.on('message', message=>{
  const user = message.author;
  const swearWords = ["fuck", "dick", "pussy", "vagina", "bsdk", "saale", "kutte", "bitch", "die", "mf", "bish", "fag","ass","nigga","nigger","fack"];
  if (swearWords.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word)) ) {
      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                 .setTitle('Chat F!lter')
                  .setColor(0xff0000)
                  .setDescription('<@' + message.author.id + '> You have been caught being toxic! , You are muted for a minute');
                  message.channel.send(embed);
                  const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name == 'muted'); 
    message.member.roles.add(role);
        setTimeout(() => {message.member.roles.remove(role)}, 60*1000);
  }});

bot.login(token);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete discord bot message after time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67153858/how-do-i-delete-discord-bot-message-after-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.channel.send()` returns a promise, you can resolve the promise and then use the `<message>.delete({ timeout: 'time-goes-here' })` method, so your code would look like this.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Client();
const token = 'token-goes-here';

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    bot.user.setActivity('YOU', { type: 'WATCHING' });
    console.log('This bot is online!');
});

bot.on('message', message=>{
  const user = message.author;
  const swearWords = ["fuck", "dick", "pussy", "vagina", "bsdk", "saale", "kutte", "bitch", "die", "mf", "bish", "fag","ass","nigga","nigger","fack"];
  if (swearWords.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word)) ) {
      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                 .setTitle('Chat F!lter')
                  .setColor(0xff0000)
                  .setDescription('<@' + message.author.id + '> You have been caught being toxic! , You are muted for a minute');
                  // send and deleting the embed
                  message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })); // delete embed after 5 seconds (5000 ms)
                  const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name == 'muted'); 
    message.member.roles.add(role);
        setTimeout(() => {message.member.roles.remove(role)}, 60*1000);
  }});

bot.login(token);
```

Comment: a little explaination on whatever you used here would be helpful also im grateful you replied

Comment: They used `.then()`. They put msg as the variable, which would have the value of the message you sent. Then, it deletes that message with a timeout (delay). This works since messages are promises.

Comment: @DivyanshJain ^ , if it helped consider marking it as a correct answer please :)